# Which data type should be used to store values like 999999999 in C?

Tags: c

I want to store integer values like 999999999 or greater.

Can someone please suggest a suitable data type? I tried `unsigned long long` but it didn't work.

Comment: It should - that'd fit into 32-bits even. You did include the [constant type suffix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k2xf226.aspx), didn't you?

Comment: "i tried unsigned long long" - you didn't try hard enough. `unsigned long long` is guaranteed to store up to at least `2**64-1`, which is `18446744073709551615`. If you're using an obsolete compiler that doesn't have `long long`, you'll need an implementation-specific solution to go beyond the guaranteed limit of `unsigned long`, which is `4294967295`.

Comment: `unsigned long long` (and `uint64_t`) are C99 specific. If you're limited to a C89 compiler, use `unsigned long` or, if that isn't enough, a bigint library.

Comment: *Show* what you tried - and how it "failed".

Comment: @pmg +1 for bigint library. A good one is [GNU MP](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: @SteveJessop: That's only half the rent. You also need the `LL` literal specifier.

Comment: @Kerrek: true, Rup already mentioned that. Anyway it depends how those big values are computed - they might not be literals. `unsigned long i = 1000; i*= 1000; i*=1000; i-= 1;` gives me 999999999 with no `(U)LL` suffix required. We might also add that `unsigned long long` and the `LL` suffix are only two thirds the rent - you also need the `%llu` printf format ;-)

Comment: it dumped core while doing so. I need to check which cc im using.

Comment: @KerrekSB, @Steve, the specifier for literals that makes a real difference is `U`. All constants then have a type that fits them.

Comment: @WTP: GNU MP is not a good library. It commits one of the worst possible offenses for a library, aborting the calling program when it can't obtain enough memory for an operation rather than reporting an error. This makes it completely unusable for any moderate to high robustness purposes, and I would generally recommend against learning it anyway since you'll have to relearn something better (and retrofit all your code) as soon as you find yourself needing stability...

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it's just a matter of notation:

```
unsigned long long t = 9999999999999999999;
```

will fail, whereas:

```
unsigned long long t = 9999999999999999999ULL;
```

will work.

Comment: Why should the first fail? The standard says (basically) that a constant has a type that fits it, if such a type exists.

Comment: I don't know *why* it fails, but apparently it does with GCC.

Comment: That particular value happens not to fit in a 64 bit `long long`. In C99 a decimal constant with no suffix is *always* signed, so the value doesn't fit in any permitted type, and with `gcc -pedantic-errors` it won't compile.

Comment: @JensGustedt, @wormsparty: if the compiler isn't fully C99 compliant here or isn't running in C99 mode, you can get `long` instead of `long long` for the suffix-less constant.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you add the correct literal specifier:

```
unsigned long long int a = 12ULL; // guaranteed up to 18,446,744,073,709,551,615
unsigned long int b = 13UL;       // guaranteed up to              4,294,967,295
unsigned int c = 14U;             // guaranteed up to                     65,535
```

The standard guarantees that your number will fit into a `long` or `long long` (whether signed or unsigned), though on most contemporary platforms it'll also fit an ordinary `int`.

If you truly need *arbitrary* precision, you'll need a software solution, like [GMP](http://gmplib.org).

Comment: The only necessary suffix here is `U`. A constant always has a type that fits it, if such a type exists.

Comment: Actually those numbers depend on platform and compiler. On all 32 bits x86 compilers I know, `unsigned int` and `unsigned long int` have the same size (4 bytes). On 64 bits, `unsigned long int` is the same as `unsigned long long int` with 8 bytes. No modern compiler on 32 bits architecture has `unsigned int` as short as 2 bytes (limit of 65,535), that is `unsigned short int`.

Comment: @lvella: The standard makes requirements about the minimal range for the integral types; those are the ones I stated. Any implementation is free to provide *larger* ranges.

Comment: @JensGustedt: Are you sure about that? That's decidedly not true for long doubles, single-precision floats and wide chars; why would it be true for ints?

Comment: @Jens: although you still want the `LL` part of the suffix for something like `unsigned long long i = 1000ULL * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 - 1;`, where an `unsigned int` would wrap around. Or you can cast, of course.

Comment: @Steve, sure as soon as you are doing arithmetic in expressions you need it. But none of the examples so far needed it :)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how many 9's you need.

```c
char *nines = calloc(1, number_of_nines+1);
memset(nines, '9', number_of_nines);
```

works well...

Comment: does it allows me to do numeric operations on it? does c do that?

Comment: If you write functions to do it like you learned in elementary school, then yes...

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use the number for logic, then use an array to get or set the data; or, if you are going to use the number for storing, then use a string.